# Как сымитировать другое время для сайта?

Tags: html, requests

Всем добрый день. Вопрос заключается в том что есть сайт, к примеру вот [этот](https://www.bybit.com/ru-RU/nft/detail?id=136388) и там есть обратный счетчик времени, после которого откроется форма покупки и потом кнопка оплатить. Я хотел бы как нибудь получить запрос, который будет отправляться после нажатия кнопки оплатить, мне подсказали, что можно каким то образом поиграться с временем и сымитировать так, что сайт будет думать, что уже прошло время и началась фаза покупок и тем самым можно будет достать запрос. Но я не могу найти каким образом это можно сделать.

Comment: Возможно и нельзя это сделать. Смотря как и что там реализовано, данные могут синхронизироваться с сервером. Если хорошо писали , иначе каждый желающий бы переделывал js и что то менял. Это чисто теория.

Comment: Понял, спасибо за ответ. Возможно вы ещё знаете и можете подсказать, возможно ли найти в исходниках сайта этот запрос? Или его тоже нельзя так просто найти и он может быть спрятан?И тогда единственным вариантом будет это ждать окончания таймера и надеятся, что запрос будет успешным.